# Might basic finance questions be on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Could stuff taught in introductory finance at university level which may involve topics such as WACC, risk-adjusted return, dividends (involving stuff like DDM or gordon growth; I get that Modigliani-Miller is on-topic), derivatives (not pricing, just basic stuff like definitions, payoffs, etc), arbitrage strategies, etc?

All the topics I listed were discussed in finance classes I took, but they were mentioned, though not really but sometimes discussed, in economics classes I took or of which I have heard.

Finally, I believe this question differs from [this other one](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/is-finance-under-our-domain) because I am asking specifically about basic finance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finance is on topic on this site. There's even a tag for it ([finance](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance)). The only caveat is that the answer that you will get will be coming from an economics perspective. There is plenty of common ground covered between this site and https://quant.stackexchange.com/. The site that you choose to use will probably determine the kind of answer that you receive---an economics perspective versus a "quant" perspective. Between the two sites, you should be able to find a place for your question.

Possible cases of when the question might not belong are if it's an accounting-type question or if it is a question that might belong on https://money.stackexchange.com/. In any case, feel free to ask and let us figure it out later. It's very easy to transfer a question from one site to another if needed.

Also, we are always looking for more questions!